# Informix select into external syntax error

Tags: informix

Can somebody please tell me what is the problem with the following informix statement :

```
SELECT *  FROM
     (some big query here) 
 INTO EXTERNAL empdata(selected_date date, land char, grund integer, some_user varchar, nr decimal(15))
 USING (DATAFILES("DISK:/usr1/tbodan.out"))
```

I get a syntax error near INTO EXTERNAL empdata.

**UPDATE**

Informix version is 11.7 and omitting the column definition only brings the following error  `Error: Virtual column must have explicit name.`

Comment: I assume that the description of the error being detected at 'INTO EXTERNA empdata' was a typo in the question and not in the SQL.  And I assume you got the endearing, unhelpful -201 "A syntax error has occurred" message?  Which version of Informix is your database using?  You might use `onstat -V` from the command line, or `SELECT DBINFO('version', 'full') FROM sysmaster:sysdual` to find out via a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,so the problem was actually in the select query.

The query returns more  columns that do not have an explicit name and are tagged as "expression" that is why the `Error: Virtual column must have explicit name.` popped up.

I solved this by using aliases for those columns. Then used the syntax suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44033251/2960896).

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow the documented syntax at [INTO EXTERNAL clause](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_2091.htm#ids_sqs_2091).

I think your problem is that you tried to provide column names and data types for the table.

This SQL worked for me:

```
SELECT * FROM elements
  INTO EXTERNAL ext_elements
 USING (DATAFILES("DISK:/Users/jleffler/tmp/ext-elements.table"))
```

This SQL did not, generating a -201 "A syntax error has occurred" error:

```
SELECT * FROM elements
  INTO EXTERNAL ext_elements(atomic_number INTEGER, symbol CHAR(3),
                             name CHAR(20), atomic_weight DECIMAL(8,4),
                             pt_period SMALLINT, pt_group CHAR(2), stable CHAR(1))
 USING (DATAFILES("DISK:/Users/jleffler/tmp/ext-elements.table"))
```

Testing on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.5, using Informix 12.10.FC4.